# Display my location marker above all others

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using google maps in my android app, and I wanted to use a custom myLocation marker
I need it to be on top of the other markers, how can make it be on top ?

Comment: The Z order of markers is related to the order they are added to the map. If you want to make sure your marker is on top just add it last and it should be added over any other markers in that area. If have something more complex in mind please provide more details.

Comment: i tried that, still it is under the others

Comment: I just want it to be visible at all times, and if i rotate/zoomout/zoomin the map, it seems to hide behind the other markers

Comment: you can try making all your markers flat except for your location icon, other than that I dont think there is a way to do what you want

Comment: that, unfortunately, does not help

Comment: Any solution for this problem guys.?

Answer (score 2):

> Try below code, it helped me to show marker above to all other markers

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(mLatLng)
.title("" + name)
.snippet("" + pingDate)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon))
.zIndex(yourZIndex));
```

> Here is  screenshot of my application

[image]